# How can I access states from an upper layer when computing gates in Tensorflow RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to modify Tensorflow's LSTM to take into account the hidden state of the *upper* layer at the previous timestep when calculating gate values.

I built the following model:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(timesteps, feature_size))

l = customLSTM(units=state_size,
               return_sequences=True)(inputs)
l = customLSTM(units=state_size,
               return_sequences=True)(l)

output = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_size, activation='softmax'))(l)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

"customLSTM" is basically Tensorflow's "LSTM" layer where I'm calling an adapted version of "standard_lstm" [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py). In this step function, the states h(t-1) and x(t) are multiplied by their respective weights and summed:

```
z = K.dot(x_t, kernel)
z += K.dot(h_tm1, recurrent_kernel)
```

I would like to add another weighted state h(l+1,t-1), that is the hidden state of the previous timestep and above layer:

```
z += K.dot(h_lp1_tm1, another_kernel)
```

However, I don't know how I can access the hidden state from the upper layer at the previous timestep. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you try to exemplify what are you doing and what errors are you getting please? That could help you get a more direct answer.

Comment: @Pimenta, I edited my question, maybe that helps clearing things up?